# what is the easiest way to extract PCIe capabilitiy + state?

Tags: bash

I can get the data using `sudo lspci -vvv` but then I have to parse it, and it gets a bit tricky...

I can grep the relevant PCIe name I need, and then use `-A` to take N lines after the name, but it isn't robust. I can also split the outcome by `\n\n` and then process it, grepping the relevant pcie name, but again, feels not good.

`cut` or `tr` doesn't work with strings AFAIK, so I can't process using delimiter `\n\n` and so I feel a bit stuck

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is with a regular expression that can match multiple lines of a string that consists of the whole output of the `lspci` command. There may be a command to do this, but I don't know of it, so typically you have to do this from a language such as perl or Python.
For brevity, here is an example perl command to extract just the flag `NonFatalErr`
for the "Root Complex" capability of my audio chipset.

```perl
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
my $data = join('',<>);
if ( $data =~ m{
 Audio\ device:
 .*?Capabilities:[^\n]*Root\ Complex
 .*?DevSta:
 .*?(NonFatalErr.)
 }sx ){
        print "found DevSta: $1 !\n";
}
```

Put this in a file `myprog`, do `chmod +x myprog`, and pipe the `lspci` output
into it.

Regular expressions are a big subject which cannot be explained here, but
are worth learning about as they are very powerful.

The above perl reads all the input into a single string `$data`. Then a
match *m{regex}flags* is done on it with perl flag `s` to make "." match
newlines, and flag `x` to ignore whitespace in the regex.

"Audio\ Device" matches "Audio Device" in the data, and `.*?` skips over
the minimal number of characters ("non-greedy") until the rest of the regex
matches. One of several "Capabilities:" is found, but we continue until we find the one with "Root Complex" with no intervening
newlines (`[^\n]*`). There are several "NonFatalErr" strings, but we want
the one for `DevSta`. We capture the string (using `()`) plus one following character
`(NonFatalErr.)` which is the flag's value (`+` or `-`). We print the capture which perl saved in variable `$1`.

This is a proof of concept, not a tutorial, so please use it as motivation for your own solution.